# Press "Visit product" button only if an <article> has an <li> class of "availability"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the following source code:

```
<form method="POST" data-component="compareForm" action="#">
    <div class="row tsp" data-component="list-page-product">
        <article id="123">
            <div id='product'>
            </div>
            <div class="stock">
                <ul class="simple" data-product="availability">
                    <li class="available">
                        <i class="icon-tick"></i>
                            <span>Delivery available</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
            
            <div data-component="CT">
                <button class="TT" type="button">Visit product</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="1234">
            <div id='product'>
            </div>
            <div class="stock">
                <ul class="simple" data-product="availability">
                    <li class="available">
                        <i class="icon-tick"></i>
                            <span>Delivery available</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
            
            <div data-component="CT">
                <button class="TT" type="button">Visit product</button>
            </div>
        </article>

    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to press the "Visit product" button if I found a class name of "available". In this example only article id="123" should be a match.

My code is:

```
if self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='available']"):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="TT"]').click()
```

The first error is that it cannot locate an element using XPath. I don't know what to do next. Any input is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to click visit product for every available product or only for the first one ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would search for articles then iterate and if available class is found click.

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()

d.get('URL')

articles = d.find_elements_by_xpath('//article')

for article in articles:
    try:
        available = article.find_element_by_class_name(
            '//li[@class="available"]')
        article.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="TT"]').click()
    except:
        pass
```

If button class is not only 'TT' or li class is not only 'available' this will not work. In that case you could use `find_element_by_class_name`.

Comment: articles = item_url.find_elements_by_xpath('//article')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: Post your code please... What is item_url? You have to navigate it with webdriver.get(url) then call webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath